# Объединить синонимичные метки {"замыкание", "замыкания", "closure"}

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Объединить:

- [замыкания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) - 28 вопросов;
- [замыкание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) - 11 вопросов;
- [closure](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closure) - 7 вопросов.

(по состоянию на 06.01.2018)

Эти метки нужно объединить, так как ими уже отмечены примерно соразмерные параллельные множества вопросов.

Comment: Интересно, почему-то вопросы в основном по [tag:javascript], ну и [tag:php] встречается.

Comment: Есть ещё [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) – диалект Лиспа, работающий на JVM.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну, это совсем другая история. Даже одна буква многое меняет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin в русских сообществах укрепились легкоразличимые слова для этих двух вещей: "замыкание" и "кложура".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синонимизировать и объединить, основной сделать [замыкания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f). По аналогии как с другими метками делали.